# Why do I need interface when I can implement full class?

Tags: java, class, oop

I tried to understand the use of `interface` and read [this article](http://www.learn-java-tutorial.com/Interfaces.cfm#.UiNk0D8deh8) which says:

> Interfaces define a standardized set of commands that a class will
>   obey.
>
> The commands are a set of methods that a class implements.
>
> The interface definition states the names of the methods and their
>   return types and argument signatures. There is no executable body for
>   any method that is left to each class that implements the interface.

I would like to ask why do I need to state name of methods and their return types and argument signatures in an `interface` while I can implement them directly in a `class`?

Comment: in that way you don't marry with no one implementation, only with a contract

Comment: Start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), and you'll probably land [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html). Voting to close though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simplest way I would say the main use is polymorphism i.e, ability to perform the same operation on a number of different objects.

From [here](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3b_OOPInheritancePolymorphism.html#zz-6.6):-

> An interface is a contract (or a protocol, or a common understanding)
>   of what the classes can do. When a class implements a certain
>   interface, it promises to provide implementation to all the abstract
>   methods declared in the interface. Interface defines a set of common
>   behaviors. The classes implement the interface agree to these
>   behaviors and provide their own implementation to the behaviors. This
>   allows you to program at the interface, instead of the actual
>   implementation. One of the main usage of interface is provide a
>   communication contract between two objects. If you know a class
>   implements an interface, then you know that class contains concrete
>   implementations of the methods declared in that interface, and you are
>   guaranteed to be able to invoke these methods safely. In other words,
>   two objects can communicate based on the contract defined in the
>   interface, instead of their specific implementation.
>
> Secondly, Java does not support multiple inheritance (whereas C++
>   does). Multiple inheritance permits you to derive a subclass from more
>   than one direct superclass. This poses a problem if two direct
>   superclasses have conflicting implementations. (Which one to follow in
>   the subclass?). However, multiple inheritance does have its place.
>   Java does this by permitting you to "implements" more than one
>   interfaces (but you can only "extends" from a single superclass).
>   Since interfaces contain only abstract methods without actual
>   implementation, no conflict can arise among the multiple interfaces.
>   (Interface can hold constants but is not recommended. If a subclass
>   implements two interfaces with conflicting constants, the compiler
>   will flag out a compilation error.)